# Is there a way to conclude this proof about showing the existence of $\xi>a$ such that $f'(\xi)=0$ for $f$ differentiable on $(a,+\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Assume that $f$ is continuous function on $[a,+\infty)$ and differentiable on $(a,+\infty)$. If $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=f(a)$, then there exists $\xi>a$ such that $f'(\xi)=0$.

My attempt: let $x>a$, by the mean value theorem there exists $\xi_x \in (a,x)$ such that:
$$f'(\xi_x)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$
Since by hypothesis $\lim_{x \to+\infty} f(x)=f(a)$, it follows that:
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=0$$
Hence:
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} f'(\xi_x)=0$$
However, even if $\xi_x \in (a,x)$ and $(a,x) \to (a,+\infty)$ when $x \to +\infty$ with $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f'(\xi_x)=0$, this is not enough to conclude because I need the existence of a point $\xi>a$ and not a limit. Moreover, since the derivative needs not to be continuous, even if $\xi_x \to \xi$ as $x\to+\infty$ I can't say anything about $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f'(\xi_x)$. But this seems very close to the result, so I would like a suggestion to complete this or another strategy if this is will never work.

Comment: Prove by contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $f$ is constant, the result is obvious. So, suppose $f$ non constant.

- Because $f$ non constant,  there is $x_0>a$ s.t. $f(x_0)\neq f(a)$. Suppose WLOG that $f(x_0)>f(a)$.
- Take $u\in (a,x_0)$ s.t. $f(a)<f(u)<f(x_0)$ (why such $u$ exist ?).
- Since $f(x)\to f(a)$ whenever $x\to \infty $, there is $M>x_0$ s.t. $f(x)<f(u)$ for all $x>M$.
- Take $v\in [x_0, M]$ s.t. $f(v)=f(u)$ (why such $v$ exists ?)
- I let you finish.